# Into which subcategories can reinforcement learning be divided?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-methods, temporal-difference-methods, model-based-methods, model-free-methods

In the course of a scientific work, I will discuss the different types of reinforcement learning. However, I have difficulties to find these different types.

So, into which subcategories can reinforcement learning be divided? For example, the following subdivisions seem to be useful

- Model-free and Model-based
- Dynamic Programming, Monte Carlo and Temporal Difference

Any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two suggestions are not mutually exclusive. If you go by this process, you'll have to do a "Cartesian product" of a bunch of different RL categorizations which would get out of hand. I recommend, if you can, to describe some sort of "RL taxonomy" instead. By this I mean describing different RL characterizations without assuming they're mutually exclusive.

To add to your list :

- On-policy or off-policy
- Value based or policy gradient

Comment: Maybe you could include a diagram like [this one](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro2.html). It's your choice, but sometimes diagrams help.

Comment: +1 for the diagram nbro posted, that's a great visualization for what I was trying to describe